# Dates - start and end vs only start

Tags: mysql, architecture

In my database, I have a prices table. Prices are valid for a set period of time or forever, but there always is a valid price at a given time.

I was wondering would you rather have a `starts_at` and `ends_at` columns, where `ends_at` would always be equal to the previous `starts_at` value, or only a `starts_at` and query for the last one at a given date?

I can see the benefit of having `between` capabilities, but on the other side it's a hassle to update a row, since it might impact `ends_at` dates here and there.

Comment: Hmmm... if you can change servers, you could do worse than looking at MariaDB's [temporal tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/temporal-tables/), or you could look at PostgreSQL's [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) - I'm not sure what's available in this area for MySQL!

Comment: You do not need in `end` column - the end of the price actuality period is defined by the next `start` value if exists. Also you may easily convert this structure to `start-end` representation with according query or view at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only thousands of rows, do whatever.  If you have millions of rows, then you will find that "between start and end" is inefficient, and there is no `INDEX` possible to make it fast.

When you have both a start and end in each row, the Optimizer does not know whether there are overlapping ranges.  So it has to assume there could be multiple results for any lookup you do.

[*ip-ranges*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges) shows how to make non-overlapping ranges work efficiently.  (Alas, it will take some adapting to change to your application.)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either way.

If you like the idea of `between`, then I would add a trigger on after insert that updates the `ends_at` of the previous record/instance.

**Triggers** are the best way to have duplicate(non-normalised) data synchronised.